# Can bù (不) change its pronunciation to bú?

Tags: pronunciation, sandhi

When I first learned 不，the accompanying pinyin was given as

> bù (falling tone).

But I've also been doing Pimsleur Chinese lessons and there is the example

> wo bú hùi shuo ying wen

and here 不 is pronounced with a rising tone.

My question is:

> Is there a rule to when it is bù and when bú? Or does it depend on the speaker's dialect?

Comment: phenomenon called tone sandhi, https://eastasiastudent.net/china/mandarin/tone-change-rules/   These rules are **not normally reflected in the tone marks** of pinyin; you just have to know them

Comment: Thank you @user6065 that is very helpful information!

Answer (score 8):

The [rule about sandhi of 不](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/b6e4b418b42acfc789eb172ded630b1c59ee9b6a.html) is:

1. It's pronounced in the original tone (the 4th tone) when being used alone or at the end.

> 规律一:单念或末尾时念本调。
>
> 不、就不、毫不、决不、都不、无不、何不、我偏不

2. It's pronounced in the 2nd tone when being used before a 4th tone.

> 规律二：去声前念阳平。
>
> 不对、不算、不便、不怕、不必、不屑  不怕、不当、不定、不动、不利、不顺

3. It's pronounced in the 4th tone when being used before a tone other than the 4th tone.

> 规律三：非去声前念去声。
>
> 不听、不悲、不分、不蒙、不穿、不飞 不同、不曾、不行、 不纯、不回、不白  不美、不想、不好、不许、不准、不满

4. It's pronounced in the neutral tone when being used in the middle of words.

> 规律四：夹在词语中间变轻声。
>
> 想不开、起不来、行不行、大不了、对不起、大不大、谈不谈、拿不动、好不好、打不开

Answer (score 5):

`bù` becomes `bú` when it precedes a falling tone.

I don't know -> wǒ bù zhī dǎo

I don't do -> wǒ bú zuò